# Why do we pass an adapter to the Section Indexer object?

Tags: android, listview, sectionindexer

Why do we pass an adapter to the Section Indexer object in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually says in android documentation but basically it stands for fast scrolling.I recommend you to read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html and if you want to implement http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/12/android-listview-sectionindexer-fastscroll.html this link.However android developer site explains more detailed.